# Why do so many password tutorials, after hashing a password, use "mysql_real_escape_string"?

Tags: php, security, hash, sql-injection, mysql-real-escape-string

I don't see the need, when the input is taken as a string and hashed. Wouldn't hashing it effectively, well, sanitize the input? It seems like a waste of about a couple hundred CPU cycles, not significant, but I don't see the need.

I realize I'll need to use crypt to protect my passwords.

Edit: As an example:

```
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password = strip_tags($password); 
$password = sha1($password);
```

It makes no sense to me.

Comment: Obligatory comment. Please do not use **`mysql_*`** for new code as these functions have been deprecated. Instead use **`mysqli_*`** or PDO forms.

Comment: Here's a very basic example of what I'm talking about: $password = sha1($password);

Comment: This is taken from [php-login.net](http://php-login.net) (I might have modified it, dont remember)

`$hash_cost_factor = (defined('HASH_COST_FACTOR') ? HASH_COST_FACTOR : 10);
            
$user_password_hash = password_hash($_POST['user_password_new'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array('cost' => $hash_cost_factor));`

Comment: Note that `bcrypt` or such should be used over any fast hashing algo's (like sha1). But that wouldn't change your question.

Comment: Why do people keep suggesting bcrypt when I keep saying I realize I need to use crypt. I'm referencing tutorials!

Comment: BTW applying `strip_tags()` to input is in general the wrong way to tackle XSS (use `htmlspecialchars()` on output instead, or a templating language that does it automatically for you). But it's especially the wrong thing for passwords - it will remove part of the password, leaving the user with a weaker password than they thought they had. For example user enters `a<(Sr2-3wEg>` as password, but can log in using just `a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**The Internet is full of chimpanzees**](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/33471)

That's the main reason why it is always mentioned.
In these tutorials, where only raw PHP without even grain of abstraction is used, it's indeed superfluous.

However, in fact, in a real application `mysql_real_escape_string` or equivalent **have** to be applied. Not the way it is described in aforementioned tutorials but anyway.

In a sanely designed application database layer have to be **separated** from other logic. And **by the time of the query execution it have to be totally ignorant of the data source or nature.** Means all the data have to be treated the same way. I.e. strings have to be quoted and escaped.

Thus, your password have to be sent to database layer, and treated there as a regular string. And, depends on the layer architecture, it may be escaped and quoted, or sent as a parameter separated from the query, or encoded some way - **but that shouldn't be our concern at all.**

> Wouldn't hashing it effectively, well, **sanitize** the input?

Note the emphasized word.

Your particular confusion coming from the misinterpreting the purpose of `mysql_real_escape_string` or similar function. In fact, **it does sanitize nothing.** What it really does is **part of required formatting**. A string, being placed into SQL query, have to be properly formatted. Always. Despite of the source, contents, or constellations interposition.

After all, some hashing function may return **binary** string that pretty much can contain a special character. But again - why bother at all? These CPU cycles don't worth a fraction of overall sanity and security of application.

Comment: +1. Removing the SQL-escape puts invisible coupling between the hash algorithm and the data access layer. Change one of them and you run the risk of making the other insecure (or just broken). OK, by avoiding the string op you get a very marginally faster program, but it is almost never worth the price in maintainability and risk.